# Displaying amount of guilds as activity

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I have this code to make it say "Watching (amount of servers my bot is in) servers!"

```
const activities_list = [
  "with the &help command.", 
  "with the developers console",
  "with some code", 
  "with JavaScript",
  client.guilds.size + " servers!"
];

client.on('ready', () => {
  setInterval(() => {
    const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * (activities_list.length - 1) + 1);
    client.user.setActivity(activities_list[index]);
  }, 5000);
});
```

But it gives me this when I see it on discord

"0 servers!"

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you're declaring the string before the client is ready (when you type a string with a variable it's saved with that value). Try declaring it in the `setInterval` argument:

```
client.on("ready", () => {
  setInterval(() => {
    let activities = ["your_strings", `${client.guilds.size} servers!`],
      index = Math.floor(Math.random() * (activities_list.length - 1) + 1);
    client.user.setActivity(activities[index])
  }, 5000);
});
```